# Allowing access to only one virtual host on an Apache 2 configuration, denying all others

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Suppose that in a simplified scenario, I have a server hosting a single virtual host under Apache 2, and I would like any other attempt to access the server via IP or any other host to be denied. Further, I'd like an attempt to access the virtual host by HTTP to redirect to HTTPS.

Suppose the host is myhost.company.com, so the scenario is:

- https://myhost.company.com should work
- http://myhost.company.com should redirect to https://myhost.company.com
- any other web access by host, IP, etc. to the box should be denied

This seems like it shouldn't be too difficult to do (should it?) but thus far the only way I've been able to make it work is by defining the host and the redirect, and then sending all other traffic to some dummy directory on the server that has been manually forbidden.

I'd like to be able to do it in the Apache configuration though, if possible. Is it? In all of my other attempts, with "Deny" etc. it still allows other IP/host accesses through.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the `_default_` vhost to return whatever error code you consider to count as "denied" for all requests; that'll do the trick nicely.

Comment: Try as I might, I can't get this to work. With a _default_:443 virtual host set to deny requests, and my other *:443 virtual host set with the appropriate ServerName to myhost.company.com, any request to https://anyhost.company.com still displays https://myhost.company.com rather than being denied. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? It feels like I've tried everything, but as is usually the case, probably not.

Comment: Actually, it just dawned on me that the hostname is probably unreadable by Apache prior to routing it, since the request headers are part of the encrypted content -- so the server probably has no idea what hostname is being requested, and is just pulling the first SSL host that it finds in the configuration chain. Does this sound correct? If so, it means that what I was hoping to do is actually not possible, but does make sense. The `_default_`:80 solution does work for non-HTTPS requests.

Comment: You can't do a default setup for HTTPS requests without a certificate that matches any valid FQDN.  I believe Diginotar could hook you up with one of those.